# Android: fail to get JSON array from server

Tags: php, android, arrays, json, server

I am working on a personal project which I need to send some data to the database and the database should return the detailed information (in JSON format). However, my app doesn't receive any response from the server (it returns a null value). Can anybody help me? Thanks. The following the is my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveTask;

public class InventoryBackground extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

String inventory_url = "http://10.100.50.19/inventory.php";


Context ctx;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
Activity activity;
AlertDialog.Builder builder;

public InventoryBackground(Context ctx){
    this.ctx = ctx;
    activity = (Activity) ctx;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Searching From Database...");
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    try{
        URL url = new URL(inventory_url);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
        OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));

        String part_id;

        part_id = params[0];


        String data = URLEncoder.encode("partid","UTF-8") +"="+ URLEncoder.encode(part_id,"UTF-8");


        bufferedWriter.write(data);
        bufferedWriter.flush();
        bufferedWriter.close();
        outputStream.close();

        InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
        }

        httpURLConnection.disconnect();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        return stringBuilder.toString().trim();


    }


    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) { super.onProgressUpdate(values); }

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String json) {


    try{
        progressDialog.dismiss();

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");

        JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

        String code = JO.getString("code");
        System.out.println("Code = " + code);
        String message_inv_partno = JO.getString("message_inv_partno");

        if (code.equals("partid_true"))
        {

            TextView partID = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.tv_inventory_data_partno);



            partID.setText(message_inv_partno);

        }

        else if (code.equals("partid_false")) {


        }

    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }





    }
}
```

Comment: Is your server responds correctly when using postman

Comment: Ah, solved, thank you!!